# Changing 'user-ops' to 'user-adm' in /etc/ssh/ssh_config for every user

Tags: ssh

**Question:** We have a server A with a list of local users, all named `something-ops`.
However when they ssh into every other server from A we want them to log in using `something-admin`. E.g changing `joe-ops` to `joe-admin`.

**Attempt:** I know we can have the following entry in every `/home/$USER/.ssh/config`

```
Host *
    username: joe-admin
```

However it would be a bit of an hassle to setup and maintain this for every user. Especially since `$USER` equates to `something-ops` and not just `something`.

*Can the change from `user-ops` to `user-adm` be done using a script or variable replacement in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` for every user?`*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguably when your users can't remember to log in correctly (and/or can't set up a personal  `~/.ssh/config` for themselves) they shouldn't be granted admin rights in the first place IMHO.

---

If you want to coddle your users your best bet is still to set up a personalised `~/.ssh/config`  that contains the correct

```
Host *
    username: login-admin
```

You can't use a template for `~/.ssh/config` in `/etc/skel/` to set that up for every (new) user because the files in that home directory template get copied verbatim and the mechanism doesn't provide any customisation support.

To work around that I'd ensure, for every user that doesn't have a `~/.ssh/config`  with a `Host *` entry,  that such a file gets generated and/or populated with the correct entries when they log on (for the first time).

One method is to deploy a helper script in `/etc/profile.d`.

Scripts  with  a `.sh` extension will normally be executed every time a user logs on that has a bash login shell. Similarly scripts with a `.csh`  extension will normally be executed for users that are assigned the csh.

```bash
# /etc/profile.d/ssh-config.sh 

if ! grep -qi "host *" ~/.ssh/config 2&>1
then
   if [ ! -d ~/.ssh/ ]
   then
     # Set up .ssh dirctory with correct permissions
     mkdir ~/.ssh/  && chmod 0700 ~/.ssh/
   fi
   echo "Host *
     username: ${USER%-ops}-admin" >> ~/.ssh/config  && chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/config
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a wrapper script:

```bash
#! /bin/sh
username=${USER%-ops}-admin
exec /usr/bin/ssh -l "$username" "$@"
```

Put it in `/usr/local/bin/ssh`, or in a file named `ssh` in some suitable location that comes before `/usr/bin` in `$PATH` (of course, adjust everything accordingly if `ssh` is located somewhere other than `/usr/bin`).

You could have similar wrapper scripts for `scp` and `sftp` as well if they're there. Users who need to override the script can call the actual binary's location.